# how to set Mongod config set multiple bindIp addresses

Tags: mongodb-3.4

I have the following config file:

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

storage:
  dbPath: c:\mongoDATA\db
  journal:
    enabled: true

##systemLog:
 ## destination: file
 ## path: C:\mongoDATA\log\mongodb.log   
 ## logAppend: true
```

this works, but when I try to add multiple ports like:

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.10.115
or
bindIp: "127.0.0.1, 192.168.10.115"
or
bindIp: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.10.115]
```

with or without the space after the comma it doesn't.  Could someone provide the write syntax?  Thanks  (using 3.6 community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without a space after the comma, AND the ip address has to present

Comment: "ip has to present" where the ip has to present?? @DCR

Answer (score 0):

@DCR, Wrap the comma-separated-Ips with brackets.

For example suppose that we have `multiple ips` like (`192.168.10.115`,`96.88.169.145`) and `loop back ip`(`127.0.0.1`) then the binding syntax will be as mention below

```
bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.10.115, 96.88.169.145]
```

For further your ref [Fix bindIp multiple address notation in Configuration Options](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10931), [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp),[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884021/mongodb-bind-ip-wont-work-unless-set-to-0-0-0-0) and [How to set mongod.conf bind_ip with multiple ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

For `4.4.6`, so - lets assume for series 4.x (perhaps for some of series 3.x)

The correct syntax is:

- `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<private_host_ip>,<public_host_ip>`

For each new IP just use `,` and without any spaces

For LAN access must be used the `private_host_ip`, you can use `ipconfig` or `ip a` for *Windows* and *Linux* respectively to know the ip value.
Of course for public WAN access must be used `<public_host_ip>`, it about your ISP

**Warning** both ips - `private_host_ip` and `<public_host_ip>` - are the locations where your **MongoDB** *server* is running, not the remote clients. Therefore exists the wrong assumption to add each new ip where each one represents the *remote **client** IP address* (other different than the ***server** IP address* - LAN and/or WAN), it is **not** correct.

**Note** To avoid problems is better for both use static ips, the private through your router and the second through your ISP.